# How can I tell from within Ubuntu if my liquid cooling system is pumping?

Tags: temperature, sensors, fancontrol

I have an Alienware Aurora-r4 with a liquid cooling system. Before installing Ubuntu my temperatures on Windows would always be around 25°C idle and 30°C when running several applications. Ever since I installed Ubuntu, sensors are showing the temperatures around 35°C to 45°C at idle.

Xsensors shows:

[image: xsensors window]

`sensors` shows:

[image: terminal]

I think it may have something to do with the liquid cooling system not pumping but both sensor readings does not even recognize I have liquid cooling. So how can I check and control the liquid cooling pump?

Comment: This seems like a hardware question.. Unless you mean "how to tell from the software".

Comment: I was just wondering if there was some program like lm-sensors on ubuntu that can check if the pump was pumping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to control the liquid cooling, it might act like a cpu fan & allow bios or software speed up & slow down, but I thought most liquid coolers are more like an always-on full-speed thing, they're supposed to be quieter so what's the point in slowing them down ever. Does your BIOS show anything about the cpu pump or fan speed? The sensor pictures show 3 fans, are there 3 air fans in there somewhere, or is one definitely the CPU water pump? I'd look up more info about that particular liquid cooler & see if it can report and change it's pump speed like a fan, and some liquid coolers have an air fan on the radiator too so that might be it.

I do know how to test a car's radiator to see if it's working, and a cpu liquid cooler is a little radiator... grab both hoses and see if one is cooler (the one from the rad to the cpu) and the other is hotter (from cpu to rad). If they are then it's probably working (at least a little).

Or maybe ubuntu is just running the cpu hotter for other reasons, like the cpu frequency might not be slowing down, does cpufreq-info show the governor's ondemand or conservative with the frequency within some available steps? Just saw another Q where overheating occurred because the cpufreq governor was stuck on performance=fastest which tends to be hot. Or sometimes video drivers run the cpu &/or vid card hotter in ubuntu/linux, and may need updating or trying another driver?

Comment: I felt both tubes and one of the tubes is slightly warm so I guess that means it's pumping. There are 3 fans and a fourth in the video card. I checked the video card's temperature and fan speed with NVIDIA X Server Settings and it's at around 40°C on start up. Also checked current cpu freq on the 8 cores : limits are at 1.2GHz to 3.7GHz, all currently running at 1.2GHz and governor is set to "ondemand". Everything seems to be ok so I guess Windows just does a better job at keeping my system cooler.

Comment: Everything does sound ok, at least one fan per fanspeed. I've checked which fan belongs to which reported fanspeed before by briefly slowing a fan down with my finger & watching for a slowdown in case you're wondering which is which. It's also possible that linux reports the temperatures different from windows, the amd k10 & radeon sensor drivers report weird temps in linux (like 0 to 30, seems to be an amount above some reference?) but bios & windows shows "real" temps. Or the ondemand governor speeds up all the time for me, conservative might be cooler (& maybe slower).

Comment: I'll play around with the settings. I was thinking about manually controlling the fan speeds. I will try changing the governor policy to conservative as well and see what happens. But you're right the temperature differences might just be because of a difference in how Linux and Windows report the temperatures. I had an older windows computer that was constantly getting BSOD and switched it to Linux and it's been running fine for over 2 years so I decided to switch my new computer to Linux as well. So I was surprised by the difference in temperatures but hopefully it's just bad sensor readings

Comment: I've tried comparing sensor readings in bios with the linux sensors, but some cpu & graphics heat up in seconds so by the time it boots it's hard to compare. And FYI fancontrol works for me to link any (controllable) fan to any temp sensor. Has a nice setup to see which fans it can control & decent help for picking temp & fan speed limits for a config file. My bios will override & speed up the fan too even if fancontrol doesn't want to, but maybe not all bios will do that.